# 500 STATUS WHEN CONVERTING RESPONSE TO STRING JAVA

Tags: java, spring-boot, resttemplate, bing

i am using bing api to get distance betweend two points.
I added correct data validation in my project. I would like to catch this exception:
[image]

So i would like to say to user, hey your destination address is not correct, please type correct address.

I use spring boot in my app. I use resttemplate. I would like to paste this response to String and then do something with it. Here is my code:

```
{  final String uri = "http://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/V1/Routes/Driving" + "?waypoint.0=ulica" + string1 + "&waypoint.1=ulica" + string2 +
            "&key=" + apiKey;
    String result = "";
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        result = restTemplate.getForObject(uri, String.class);
    }
```

So as you can see i want to have response in String.class.

Here is error i get (java has problem converting this response to String, that is why i got 500 response, not 404 response):

[image]

And istead of having 500 i would like to have original response from Bing (first ss in my post).
How to do it?

Comment: not sure but for me it looks like you either don't use `@ResponseBody` or `@RestController`

Comment: i have restcontroller above in endpoint, why responseBody?

Answer (score 0):

You can put the Bing API call in a try-catch block (that's a good practice anyway IMHO), catch the `RestClientException` or `RestClientResponseException` and handle it, e.g., by throwing your own application's exception which is mapped to a 404 response. E.g.:

```
final String uri = "http://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/V1/Routes/Driving" + "?waypoint.0=ulica" + string1 + "&waypoint.1=ulica" + string2 +
       "&key=" + apiKey;
try {
    String result = "";
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    result = restTemplate.getForObject(uri, String.class);
} catch (RestClientResponseException e) {
    if (e.getRawStatusCode() == 404) {
       // Application-specific exception with reasonable meaning and mapping for clients
       throw new UnknownDestinationException(e.getResponseBodyAsString());
    }
    throw e;   // Otherwise just throw it
}
```

Comment: i did not try your solution but it looks like good, it was all about catching exeptions so your solution should be also correct

Answer (score 0):

Here is solution:

```
  // Create needed variables
    final String uri = "http://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/V1/Routes/Driving" + "?waypoint.0=ulica" + string1 + "&waypoint.1=" + string2 +
            "&key=" + bing_api_key;
    String result = "";
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    // Get bing api response
    try {
        result = restTemplate.getForObject(uri, String.class);
    }
    catch (final HttpClientErrorException e) {
        result = e.getResponseBodyAsString();
    }
```

This line:
`final HttpClientErrorException e`  causes that i got 404 error, not 500.